# Finding substring in a char[] with wildcard character

Tags: c, arrays, substring, wildcard

I have an array of characters, and once the user enters a string of characters, my program needs to find string of characters in my big array of characters and report its index. However, if there's a wildcard letter such as `!`, this will represent any character in my array, how would I allow my program to read the `!` as any letter?

Example:

```
char letter [] = {a,b,c,d,e,d,s,f,e}
```

If the user enters `ab!`, the program can interpret it as abc and will return its index value of where `abc` is found.

Comment: Look for the next exclamation mark, when found add one to the iterator, ...

Comment: if user inputs `bca` what will be the output?

Comment: Can you post any code where your input matched the array *without* a wildcard? And subsequent attempt when using a wildcard? If you had got to the first step, you would have posted the big array `letter` correctly, surely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement your own version of `strstr` which adds a simple extra condition. Let us call the function `StrStr`.

```
char* StrStr(const char *str, const char *target) {
  if (!*target) return NULL;
  char *p1 = (char*)str;
  while (*p1) {
    char *p1Begin = p1, *p2 = (char*)target;
    while (*p1 && *p2 && (*p1 == *p2 || *p2 == '!')) {
      p1++;
      p2++;
    }
    if (!*p2)
      return p1Begin;
    p1 = p1Begin + 1;
  }
  return NULL;
}
```

This will simply test if `target` is found in `str` and will compare each character. If the character is a exclamation mark it will ignore if they are different.

You can call it like this and then use `result - letter` to get the position.

```
result = StrStr(letter, "b!d");

if(result != NULL) {
  int position = result - letter;
  printf("%d\n", position);
}else {
  printf("-1\n");
}
```

If you want to check for multiple occurences you can make a pointer to letter and then set it equal to the address of `letter` plus position plus one to check if the substring is found later on in the array.

```
pointer = letter;
while((result = StrStr(pointer, "a!c")) != NULL) {
  int position = result - letter;
  pointer = letter + position+1;
  printf("%d\n", position);
}
```

Here is a [live](https://ideone.com/aM9b9F) example.

Comment: Should `if (!*target) return str` be `if (!*target) return p1` (after reversing the two statements) to avoid compiler warning? Or even `return NULL`? Or would the function be better to return an index or -1, to satisfy the question without tinkering with the returned pointer?

Comment: @WeatherVane Probably, otherwise it will give false output.

Comment: result - letter gives the position, but how would I loop this if the target is found later on in the array? I tried using a while (result != NULL) but it still only provides one position

Comment: @Rain74 That'd be because you only call StrStr once. You rewrite your loop like `while((result = StrStr(letter, "b!d")) != NULL) {` And then you increment `letter` with `position`+1 inside the while loop: `letter += position+1`. That way you will not get the same position if "b!d" is found more than once.

Comment: @Linus I tried doing it but it give mes an infinite loop, and keeps printing one answer: " the element is found at 60" infinitely.

Comment: `char *result = searchArray(DNA, inputstring);` is my code where searchArray is basically the StrStr function you wrote. `while((result = searchArray(DNA, inputstring)) != NULL)` `{ int position = result - DNA; DNA += position+1; printf(" ....", position);` will only give me infinite loop. What am I doing wrong? I can't figure it out.

Comment: @Rain74 You need to make a pointer to DNA first, see my updated answer and please tick the green mark if it helped.

Comment: @Linus what type is pointer? Like " char* pointer " ? Is char* result I wrote above correct?

Comment: @Rain74 yes exactly. Look at my [example](https://ideone.com/aM9b9F) if you're unsure.

Comment: @Linus I'm looking at it but I do not know what char(buf) is or what fgets does. (Relatively new with C)

Comment: @Rain74 I added some comments explaining the code a bit. If you're still unsure of what `fgets` does, [here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) is where you can read about it.

Comment: I followed your example, but when I run the program, it executes and immediately finishes. My printf statements don't even appear.

Comment: @Rain74 Can you put your code on something like pastebin so I can take a look at it?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/jdwPkGPk My code is almost complete. I checked with the outputs, only 1 testcase doesn't work where if the user types TT*, not all elements are reported. 3 of the 7 are printed. I'm not sure if this is due to the searching algorithm or something.

Comment: @Rain74 You should use `pointer = DNA + position + 1;` instead of `pointer += position + 1;`. Otherwise it will skip over some elements. [This](http://pastebin.com/7fSZVbwC) is how your code should look like now.

Comment: @Linus thanks so much, it worked. However, if I type G**, why does it still print element 99? element 99 is a G, but there isn't any more characters after as the array ends, so is this a pointer error?

Comment: @Rain74 You probably want to change the parentheses in the `searchArray` function. You want to change `while ((*p1 && *p2 && *p1 == *p2) || *p2 == '*') {` to `while (*p1 && *p2 && (*p1 == *p2 || *p2 == '*')) {`. This will make sure the character isn't actually a NUL terminator.

Comment: @Linus i used an array instead to scan the letters, why does the program immediately execute without me even entering anything when I run it? [link](http://pastebin.com/A0wmBPCr)

Comment: @Rain74 because you forgot to use curly brackets around the if statement `if(dna <= 0)`...